# Changing background image to a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the backgound-image of a button but it doesn't work as I thought !!
the CSS is OK and it is as follows :

```
#ITA
{
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 85px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #FFFFFF url("../ITA_off.png") center center no-repeat;
    border: 0;
}
```

my javascript function in the "HEAD" is

```
function cambiaBandiera() {
    test=document.getElementById("ITA");
    test.backgroundimage="ITA_on.png";
}
```

and the button is as follows

```
<input type="button" id="ITA" onClick="cambiaBandiera()" />
```

What's wrong ?

Please HELP !

Thanx in advance

Alex

Answer (score 1):

```
test.style.backgroundImage = "url(foo.png)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `i` in `backgroundimage` should be capital eg `backgroundImage`, try this:

```
function cambiaBandiera() {
 test=document.getElementById("ITA");
 test.backgroundImage="url(ITA_on.png)";
}
```

You are trying to change the `background-image` but `-` is special character in javascript, for this reason, it should be stripped and first letter of ending word should be capitalized.

Make sure that you have an element with id `ITA` on your page.

Comment: The button is ITA and the CSS with the first image is working

Comment: @Alpan: Are you specifying the correct path, try this in js function: `test.backgroundImage="url(../ITA_on.png)";`

Comment: Ahmed : yes it's always in the same path = localhost

Comment: @Alpan67: I was talking about image path, like in my previous comment.