# Change of a background image of a button on onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why does this not work ? In Firebug, when I click on the button, it always says to me that cambiaBandiera is not defined ...

HELP

Alex

### CSS

```
#ITA{
float:right;
margin : 5px 85px;
width:40px;
height:40px;
background : #FFFFFF url("../ITA_off.png") center center no-repeat;
border:0;
}
```

---

### JAVASCRIPT (in HEAD)

```
<style type="text/javascript">
function cambiaBandiera() {
test=document.getElementById("ITA");
test.style.backgroundImage="url('../ITA_on.png')";
}
</style>
```

---

### and this is HTML

```
<div id="bandiere">
<input type="button" id="ITA" onClick="cambiaBandiera()">  </input> 
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing background image to a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934225/changing-background-image-to-a-button)

Comment: yes it's more or less a duplicate

Comment: if its a duplicate there's no need to make another question :) just carry on discussing with comments on the answers there :)

Comment: OK sry I did not know exactly how it works

Comment: You did not specify complete details there, see my answer below also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see that you put your script between **style**  tags instead of **script** tags. Maybe that is the reason it cannot find your function?

Comment: @ Peter Tilemans : Sry, I don't understand, what do you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying input in wrongly, adding not needed `</input>`:

```
<input type="button" id="ITA" onClick="cambiaBandiera()"></input>
```

It should be:

```
<input type="button" id="ITA" onClick="cambiaBandiera()" />
```

`input` tag is self closing, it does not need closing tag.

Comment: Ahmed : yes you are right but it does not change, I tried also with your tip

Answer (score 0):

Use plain CSS:

```
#bandiere:active{
    background : #FFFFFF url("../ITA_on.png") center center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Alpan67: use the CSS :active pseudo class to change the background of an element if you click on it. This technique is js-safe as well

Comment: In bandiere I will add more than ITA, that's why I created the ITA div

Answer (score 0):

JS is a standard language, so there's no need for specifying the type.

Also, it's a `script` not a `style` as well so:

```
<script>
function cambiaBandiera() {
    test=document.getElementById("ITA");
    test.style.backgroundImage="url('../ITA_on.png')";
}
</script>
```