# How to put a label on an input text password avoiding those bullets?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the best way to put a label on an input type password since it display its values as **** ?

There is no where I can put an edit button so I want to put some text like:

```
Click here...
```

so the user is able to click em edit the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input placeholder="Click here..." type="password" name="password">
```

Comment: I saw it on facebook.. way back :) in their search field :D

Answer (score 1):

1. [Use a background image and swap it out when they enter text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934315/change-of-a-background-image-of-a-button-on-onclick-event)
2. Use HTML 5's [`placeholder`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-placeholder) attribute

> The placeholder attribute represents a short hint (a word or short
>   phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry when the control has
>   no value. A hint could be a sample value or a brief description of the
>   expected format. The attribute, if specified, must have a value that
>   contains no U+000A LINE FEED (LF) or U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)
>   characters.
>
> The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a
>   label. For a longer hint or other advisory text, the title attribute
>   is more appropriate.
>
> These mechanisms are very similar but subtly different: the hint given
>   by the control's label is shown at all times; the short hint given in
>   the placeholder attribute is shown before the user enters a value; and
>   the hint in the title attribute is shown when the user requests
>   further help.
>
> User agents should present this hint to the user, after having
>   stripped line breaks from it, when the element's value is the empty
>   string or the control is not focused (or both), e.g. by displaying it
>   inside a blank unfocused control and hiding it otherwise.
>
> Here is an example of a mail configuration user interface that uses
>   the placeholder attribute:

```
<fieldset>  
  <legend>Mail Account</legend>  
    <p><label>Name: <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="John Ratzenberger"></label></p>  
    <p><label>Address: <input type="email" name="address" placeholder="john@example.net"></label></p>  
    <p><label>Password: <input type="password" name="password"></label></p>  
    <p><label>Description: <input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="My Email Account"></label></p> 
</fieldset>
```