# Click on the button to Change the button background Image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a button with a background image .

**HTML**

```
<input name="" type="button" value=" " style="background:url(http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/1815/iconanalyticsaccessacce.png)
 no-repeat center; width:13px; height:11px; border:none;">
```

[js Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/saifrahu28/eCkGQ/4/)

What I would like to add there is when I click the button the background image should change and become another image (Dark image ) . Here is the [link](http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/1815/iconanalyticsaccessacce.png) of that image what should replace with. and again click in the Dark image back to light image .

I am wondering is his possible ? I am not sure how to do this . If this can be done that will be great .

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and can be done with jquery's basic functions. Did you try something ? If necessary, look up for `click` and `css`

Comment: Somebody voted to close as "not constructive" ? Is that really the right reason ?

Comment: There are many ways of doing this. Learn Javascript.

Comment: Actually I am not good a at java scripts and jquery functions

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934225/changing-background-image-to-a-button?rq=1

Comment: have an id for that button and add a toggle function and change the background using css property..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input:button').on('click',function(){
 $(this).css('background-image','url(http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/1815/iconanalyticsaccessacce.png)');
})
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/eCkGQ/5/

**Update :**

*to toggle the image*

Css:

```
.light{
  background:url('http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/1815/iconanalyticsaccessacce.png') no-repeat center;
}

.dark{
  background:url('http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/1815/iconanalyticsaccessacce.png') no-repeat center;
}
```

Html:

```
<input class='light' name="" type="button" value=" " style="width:13px; height:11px; border:none;">
```

Js:

```
$('input:button').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('dark light');
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/eCkGQ/14/

Comment: Its worked but a little problem . I would like to switch by clicking dark to light and light to gray what ever it is active . In you Example when I click the light image it goes dark but not again click in the dark back to light image again . Is this possible ?

Thanks

Comment: to toggle the style you could use a separate class and toggle it with jQuery ... something like in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eCkGQ/10/).

Comment: Thank you Very much @pXL it worked perfectly . Actually I am not good in jquery and javascripts thats why I stuck in this type of problem . I guess I have to lean this . Thanks For he answer

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout the demo at http://jsfiddle.net/eCkGQ/8/

```
<div style="Width:36px;">    
    <input name="" type="button" value=" " style="background:url(http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/1815/iconanalyticsaccessacce.png) no-repeat center; width:13px; height:11px; border:none;" id='img'/>
</div>

$('#img').click(function(){
$(this).css('background','url(http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/1815/iconanalyticsaccessacce.png)')
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion already go the answer from pXL . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this (*OP asked the same in above comments*)

**HTML**

```
<input name="" type="button" value=" " class="first" style="width:13px; height:11px; border:none;">
```

**CSS**

```
.first{
     background:url(http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/1815/iconanalyticsaccessacce.png) no-repeat center;         
}

.second{
     background:url(http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/1815/iconanalyticsaccessacce.png) no-repeat center;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
 $('input:button').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("first second");
 });
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzQ2j/)**

Comment: this is almost exactly what I suggested in the comment on pXL's answer =) So I almost need to give it a +1 lol ;-)

Comment: Thanks foe helping though you answer is same like pXL's answer

Comment: @SRaihan `foe` means `enemy`. I don't even know you man.

Comment: @SRaihan ohh You saying `foe` to me because I closed your post. I am just helping Stackoverflow to be clean. You will understand it soon if you make a good tie up with this site. No hard feelings dude. Happy that you solved this problem. :)

Comment: Hey Sorry about that I was in hurry man . Misspelled some how :( Really Sorry about that . I never makes enemies :) . Thank you and I hope you are doing good with this site and yes I hope I may get used to with this site . All the best :) OH BTW it will be for not foe :)

Comment: @Mr_Green: We've noticed that you've been including your jsFiddle links inside `<kbd>` elements recently. That element is meant to semantically indicate keyboard input. It is not there to make links look fancier. Please do not continue the use of the `<kbd>` element for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This code works without the use of new classes, it basically switches between two given images: http://jsfiddle.net/zPeD3/

HTML

```
<div style="Width:36px;">
    <input name="" type="button" value=" " style="background:url(http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/1815/iconanalyticsaccessacce.png) no-repeat center; width:13px; height:11px; border:none;" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('input').click(function() {
    var imgs = ['http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/1815/iconanalyticsaccessacce.png', 'http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/1815/iconanalyticsaccessacce.png'];
    var current = $(this).css('background-image');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + (current.contains(imgs[1]) ? imgs[0] : imgs[1]) + ')');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a css class that defines default values

```
.default{
background:url(http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/1815/iconanalyticsaccessacce.png no-repeat center;
width:13px; 
height:11px; 
border:none;
}

.new{
background:url('http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/1815/iconanalyticsaccessacce.png') no-repeat center;
width:13px; 
height:11px; 
border:none;
}
```

JQuery :

```
$('input:button').on('click',function(){
 $(this).removeClass('default');
$(this).addClass('new');
})
```

Comment: @SRaihan allways welcome